# Integrating in a rational way

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-functions

I have to integrate
$$\int \frac{x^3 + 1}{8x + \sqrt{9-x^2}}dx$$

in a rational way.

So as I understand I must find such "replacements" (I mean $u$, $du$ etc.) that would transform this function into a rational function. But I am getting frustrated while doing this, maybe because I am picking wrong variables for my $du$, I don't know..

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: The [Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) rationalize all those integrals. Your particular case can be done with $u=\sqrt{\frac{x+3}{x-3}}$, the third case in the link.

Comment: @plop Did you get that ```u``` from sqrt(9-x^2) ? Sorry I don't know how to write equations so they show up

Comment: @Norbiuxx Yes, look in the link, in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#Euler's_third_substitution). To write equations enclose them in dollar signs. For example, `$\sqrt{9-x^2}$` produces $\sqrt{9-x^2}$.

Comment: @plop Oh okay thanks. Can you show though what do you get if you use that kind of $u$? Because I still can't get rid of the roots which makes my life hard..

Comment: But to use Third Euler Substitution I think I need to have $\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}$ and I have only $\sqrt{9 - x^2}$ or nicer to say $\sqrt{(3 - x)(3 + x)}$

Comment: Solving for $x$ you get that $x=\frac{3u^2+3}{u^2-1}$. So, the numerator $x^3+1$ stays rational. Likewise the $8x$ and the $dx$ are still rational. Now, observe that $\sqrt{9-x^2}=\sqrt{-\frac{x+3}{x-3}}(x-3)^2=iu(x-3)^2$, which becomes rational.

Comment: Yes, sometimes more than one of the cases apply. The second substitution can also be used.

Comment: @plop So if it is that simple that everything stays rational and we just need to show that $\sqrt{9 - x^2} = iu(x - 3)^2$ then we don't even need to solve for $x$ in $u$ right? And where did that $i$ get from in $iu(x - 3)^2$

Comment: That $i$ was the $\sqrt{-1}$. Probably with the second substitution you can stay within the real numbers. I don't know what the goals of your exercise. If you want to integrate then you need to actually do the substitution and later integrate the resulting rational function. We did have to solve for $x$. That is how we showed that $x$ is a rational function of $u$.

Comment: Oh so that's how we get $i$. Well as for my task, the goal was to integrate this thing so everything that's left is a rational function

Comment: But I guess it is enough that I prove $\sqrt{9 - x^2}$ is rational through $u$ and everything else is left as it be because those are rational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be this:
$$\frac{x^3+1}{8x+\sqrt{9-x^2}}=\frac{(x^3+1)(8x-\sqrt{9-x^2})}{(8x)^2-(\sqrt{9-x^2})^2}=\frac{8x^4-x^3\sqrt{9-x^2}+8x-\sqrt{9-x^2}}{65x^2-9}$$
and you can factor the bottom as:
$$65x^2-9=(\sqrt{65}x+3)(\sqrt{65}x-3)$$
and split the top up and make multiple substitutions, however you still have a fraction involving a squareroot which isn't always ideal.

---

Alternatively, consider the substitution $x=3\sin(u)$, this converts your integral into:
$$\frac{27\sin^3u+1}{24\sin u+\cos u}$$
then you can use the fact that:
$$24\sin u+\cos u=\sqrt{577}\sin(u+\alpha)$$
where $\tan\alpha=\frac1{24}$ then make the substitution $v=u+\alpha$

Comment: Thank you a lot :)