# Integrate with substitution $ \int \frac{x^3+1}{5x+\sqrt{6^2-x^2}}dx $

Tags: integration, substitution

I have a task to integrate the following integral: `

$$
\int \frac{x^3+1}{5x+\sqrt{6^2-x^2}}dx
$$

and I tried to solve it, but do not know if my moves are correct.

1.
$
u=\sqrt{6^2-x^2}
$

$
u^2=6^2-x^2
$

$
u=6-x
$

$
x=u-6
$

$
dx=(u-6)'du=du
$

2.
$
\int \frac{(u-6)^3 -1}{5(u-6)+u}du
$

3. Should I now substitute $t=u-6$ or what?

Comment: $u^2=6^2-x^2$ does not imply $u=6-x$

Comment: See [Euler substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) to solve all problems like this. Substitutions that work are $u=\sqrt{\frac{6+x}{6-x}}$ (third case in the link) or $\sqrt{6^2-x^2}=xu+6$ (second case in the link).

Comment: So x= $+- \sqrt{(6+u)(6-u)}$?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137523/integrating-in-a-rational-way) more or less gives you a method.

Comment: @ArcticChar Still don't get it the value of $x$ came from in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Break up the integral as follows

\begin{align}
I=& \int \frac{x^3}{5x+\sqrt{36-x^2}}+ \frac{1}{5x+\sqrt{36-x^2}} \ dx\\
=& \int \frac{5x^4}{26x^2-36}-\frac{x^3 \sqrt{36-x^2}}{26x^2-36}+ \frac{1}{5x+\sqrt{36-x^2}} \ dx\\
=& \ \frac52 I_1-\frac12I_2+I_3
\end{align}
where the three integrals are straightforward to evaluate
\begin{align}
I_1
=& \int \frac{x^4}{13x^2-18}\ dx 
= \frac{x^3}{39}+\frac{18x}{169}+\frac{27}{169}\sqrt{\frac2{13}}\ln |\frac{\sqrt{13}x-3\sqrt2}{\sqrt{13}x+3\sqrt2}|\\
 I_2
=& \int \frac{x^3 \sqrt{36-x^2}}{13x^2-18}\ {dx}
\overset{y^2=36-x^2} = \int \frac{y^2(36-y^2)}{450-y^2}\ dy \\
=& \ \left(\frac{x^2}{39}-\frac{138}{169}\right)\sqrt{36-x^2}-\frac{270}{169} \sqrt{\frac2{13}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{13} \sqrt{36-x^2}}{15\sqrt2}\\
I_3=& \int \frac{1}{5x+\sqrt{36-x^2}}\ dx
\overset{x=6\sin t}= \int \frac{\cos t}{5\sin t+\cos t}\ dt\\
=& \ \frac1{26}\sin^{-1}\frac x6
+\frac5{26}\ln|5x+ \sqrt{36-x^2}|
\end{align}